# A question within a question, the punctuation

Tags: punctuation, questions

I'm not sure if this is the correct written way:

> *"Who took the test? Mark?"*

Is that the appropriate way to write that, or is there a punctuation mark that I'm missing?

I can always re-phrase it as,

> "*Did Mark take the test*"?

or

> "*Was it Mark who took the test*?"

But I'd like to know if the first way is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your punctuation is ortographically correct.

> In English, the question mark typically occurs at the end of a sentence, where it replaces the full stop. However, **the question mark may also occur at the end of a clause or phrase, where it replaces the comma**:
>
> Is it good in form? style? meaning?
>   or:
>
> "Showing off for him, for all of them, not out of hubris—hubris? him? what did he have to be hubrid about?—but from mood and nervousness."   - - from [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Rhetorical_question_mark)